# Kafka commit with Akka and LogRotator

Tags: apache-kafka, akka-stream

I am trying to use the Consumer.committableSource to read data from Kafka with Akka. I would then like to write the data in files on a shared folder.
When committing, we usually use something like `via(Committer.flow(committerSettings)`.

However, this method does not return the values of the Kafka stream, so afterward I cannot call something like `.runWith(LogRotatorSink.withSinkFactory(rotator, sink))` to write the data.
Here's the code without commit:

```
Consumer.committableSource(settings, Subscriptions.topics(kafkaTopics.toSet))
  .via(processor)
  .prepend(headerCSVSource)
  .via(CsvFormatting.format(delimiter =
    CsvFormatting.SemiColon))
  .runWith(LogRotatorSink.withSinkFactory(rotator, sink))
```

Here's what I think I need:

```
 Consumer
        .committableSource(settings, Subscriptions.topics(kafkaTopics.toSet))
          .via(processor)
          .prepend(headerCSVSource)
          .via(CsvFormatting.format(delimiter =
            CsvFormatting.SemiColon))
          .via(Committer.flow(committerSettings))
          .runWith(LogRotatorSink.withSinkFactory(rotator, sink))
```

But that won't work because `via(Committer.flow)` does not return the stream values (but  Flow[Committable, Done, NotUsed]).

What I need is to commit the offset only after the data has been written in the file.
If you feel that other options (like using plainSource / auto-commit) would be more appropriate I am open to considering them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass flow element to one sink, and when it succeeded, to another.

You can run a substream inside your stream. Something along this lines:

```
.via(CsvFormatting.format(delimiter = CsvFormatting.SemiColon))
.mapAsync(1) { c =>
  Source.single(c).runWith(LogRotatorSink.withSinkFactory(rotator, sink)).map(_ => c)
}
.runWith(Committer.sink(committerSettings))
```

It should work, however, after some thought, I think best would be not to use sink to write to logs, but some other way which doesn't terminate the stream.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. I wonder if, in your solution, the write to file fails will the offset be committed?

Comment: No it won't. Then what you get in `mapAsync` is failed Future, which fails the stream.